# Extract UIATableCell value

Tags: javascript, ios, ios-ui-automation

I am working on iOS-ui-Automation and would like to extract the UIATableCell value. The procedure is as following:

1. check if table view exists
2. what is in the first cell

The following code snippet of TEST.JS is used to test the App:

```
.
.
.
if ( target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()[0].checkIsValid() )
{
    UIALogger.logStart("Table view recognized ...");
    target.delay(2.0);
    var TableViewInfo = target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()[0].cells()[0]
    UIALogger.logStart(TableViewInfo);

}
```

In the instruments log I see the following:

```
UIATableView "(null)" {{99, 99}, {99, 99}}
        elements: {
            UIATableCell "xyz" {{99, 99}, {99, 99}}
            elements: {
                UIAStaticText "xyz" {{99, 99}, {99, 99}}
                UIAWebView "(null)" {{99, 99}, {99, 99}}
                elements: {
                    UIAStaticText "xyz." {{99, 99}, {99, 99}}
                }
            }
```

How would you read out "xyz" and log it out in TEST.JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the "xyz" string from an element, you should be able to use the [`.name()` method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIAElementClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/javascript/instm/UIAElement/name) on it.

In this case, it looks like that would be `TableViewInfo.cells()[0].name()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is the answer I was looking for. It worked well.

Answer (score 0):

also, you can always use the logElementTree() method. It prints the element hierarchy to the trace log right at the point it was called.

eg: `tableViews()[0].logElementTree();`

Comment: `logElementTree` produces a log, but does not return any values.